# Why does Tornado spend time in socket.send(data)?

Tags: tornado, nonblocking

I'm looking at profiles for my Tornado TCP application and I'm finding that the thread running the event loop spends about 20% time in `tornado/iostream.py::write_to_fd` in the line `self.socket.send(data)` and about 15% time in `tornado/iostream.py::read_from_fd` in the line `self.socket.recv_into(buf)`.

Given that these are non-blocking sockets, why does this take any time at all?  What are common situations for this to take time and are there any common optimizations I can do to my application to improve efficiency?

Answer (score 1):

Even though these are non-blocking sockets, the system calls still involve a context switch into and out of kernel mode. There's not a lot you can do to reduce this besides minimizing the number of such calls you make (e.g. by doing your reads and writes in larger batches).

Comment: Do you happen to have an estimate of how expensive such a context switch is?  I'm already batching communications at 5ms and am able to make this a significant cost using only a few concurrent connections on my local machine (few meaning five or so).  Also, is this the sort of thing that would be improved by switching IOStream implementations to something like `libuv`, or is this strictly a system call limitation?

Comment: It looks like the cost of system calls is generally measured in microseconds, so it doesn't sound like a complete explanation here. Maybe python's socket module is doing more than just the system call here. It would be worth doing an experiment with `uvloop`.