# Why does Asyncio spend time in socket.send(data)

Tags: python, python-asyncio, nonblocking

I'm profiling my asyncio application and find that the following stack ends up consuming a surprising amount of CPU time (like 25%)

```
mycode.py:my_stream_writer.write(my_bytes)
asyncio/streams.py::self._transport.write(data)
asyncio/selector_events.py::self._sock.send(data)
```

Given that these are non-blocking sockets I would have expected this not to take up too much time.  What can I do on my end to reduce overhead here?  I'm already batching messages into few-millisecond bins and have tried `uvloop`.

This follows on from a [similar question with Tornado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51686171/why-does-tornado-spend-time-in-socket-senddata)

Comment: Are you saturating your upstream bandwidth? If so, there’s not much you can (or need to) do. But if you’re using 100% CPU and still have lots of bandwidth available, that’s a different story.

Comment: I'm using around 40MB/s on a localhost connection binned every 500ms.  I would expect to get a few times that locally at least.  Maybe this is just very bursty behavior, `socket.send` is blocking during the bursts, and my 500ms binning is missing this behavior?

Comment: Also, even if we are saturating upstream bandwidth I'd still prefer that asyncio not block.  There is other work my application could be doing during these times.

Comment: Do you mean 25% of CPU time spent on your task or 25% of CPU time available on your system?

Comment: The Python thread running the asyncio event loop spends 25% of its time in `socket.send`

Comment: @MRocklin That might be OK. It has to spent its 100% somewhere.

Comment: I would strongly prefer that it spent that time waiting on the event loop so that it can respond quickly to new work

Comment: If I understand it correctly, waiting in the event loop's is implemented with select system call (or similar) in the kernel and does not increase user process CPU time.

Comment: Correct.  I would be totally fine if we spent time waiting in `select` rather than `socket.send`